# How do I calculate the 85th percentile value of a measure being used as a value in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure, percentile

I'm struggling with creating a measure in Power BI that gives the 'X' percentile value of a range of values created by another measure that is being used in a matrix.

In this case, I'm trying to calculate the 'x' percentile value of 'RFM M Value', which provides an Average Sale Value measure by summing the Sale Value per customer and dividing it by the Unique Number of Invoices per customer.

This measure is calculated correctly as shown in the RFM M Value values in the matrix. However, when I try and calculate the 85th percentile value of the displayed results in the RFM M Value as per the previously used logic and formula, the results are unexpected.

The formula I have used to calculate the 85th percentile is:

```
var _table = SUMMARIZE('Master File','Master File'[UniqueIDFinal],"Test",[RFM M Value])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    PERCENTILEX.INC(
        _table,
        [RFM M Value],
        0.85),
        ALLEXCEPT('Master File','Master File'[Sale Date II]))
```

It displays correctly when used in a card measure as shown in the screenshot but when I apply it to the matrix, it gives an incorrect value. Any idea as to how I can replicate the measure correctly in the matrix?

The link to the Power BI file is given below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4uya0ow1d5co85/Sample%20Power%20BI%20File.pbix?dl=0

[image]

Thank you.